# C言語の電卓で、"/0" が入力されたらエラーを表示するようにしたい

Tags: c

C言語についての質問です。
電卓問題で下記のコードを提出したところ /0 をユーザーが入力したらエラー表示が出る様なコードを書き加える様に言われたのですが、やり方が分からず、どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    char op;
    float answer;
    int r;
    r = scanf("%d%c%d", &num1, &op, &num2);
    if (r != 3 ) {
        puts("input error");
        return 1;
    }
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        answer = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        answer = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        answer = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        answer = (float)num1 / num2;
        break;
    }
    printf("%f\n", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case '/':
answer = (float)num1 / num2;
break;
```

このコードに少し足して

```
case '/':
if (num2 == 0) {
  puts("Divide by Zero");
  return 1;
}
answer = (float)num1 / num2;
break;
```

というのはいかがですか ?

Comment: ありがとうございます。